# Syncronizing Data from IBM DB2 to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database, db2, synchronization

One of my clients is using IBM DB 2 and my application is using Sql Server. For synchronizing data I am using DMS-SYNC and its working fine but the only issue is I have to also install IBM DB 2. Currently I am using trial Version and don't want to buy it. Is there any other synchronizing tool or any other method where I can synchronize without installing IBM DB2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the community-edition of Db2, sometimes called Express-C ?

See this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/db2express/index.html).

Comment: Post error code from Db2 or more precise description of the issue. "not working" is not helpful.